# I keep getting the following error thread 'main' panicked at 'Jjaanokapasao: ParseIntError { kind: InvalidDigit }', fahrenheit_celsius.rs:17:49

Tags: rust

I'm very newbie when it comes related to Rust, and I keep getting this error and honestly, I have no clue what's going on. I'm doing a Fahrenheit to Celsius, and the other way around.
Here is my code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut choose = String::new();
    println!("Choose between Celsius To Fahrenheit [1] or Fahrenheit to Celsius [2],\
    please introduce a corrected value (integer)");
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut choose)
        .expect("Failed to read!");
    // Careful with the trim, cuz it's removing all characters and it causes and error that basically, closes the CMD
    // Carriage return BE CAREFUL MAN!
    if choose.trim() == "1" {
        println!("Please, Introduce a value ");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut choose).expect("Please, enter an integer");
        let choose: i32 = choose.trim().parse().expect("Jjaanokapasao");
        ctof(choose);
    } else if choose.trim() == "2" {
        println!("Please, Introduce a value");
        io::stdin().read_line(&mut choose).expect("Please, enter an integer");
        let choose: usize = choose.trim_end().parse().expect("Failed to convert to i32");
        ftpc(choose);
    }
}


fn ctof(c: i32) {
    let celsius_to_fahrenheit: i32 = (c * (9 / 5)) + 32;
    println!("Here is your conversion: {celsius_to_fahrenheit}")
}


fn ftpc(f: usize) {
    let fahrenheit_to_celsius: usize = (f-32) * (5 / 9);
    println!("Here is your conversion: {fahrenheit_to_celsius}")
}

'''
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.read_line()` to read into a `String` will *append* to the existing data, not *overwrite* it. And you used `.trim()` it ignore the newline in your comparisons, but it still exists; it wasn't removed from the string. So if you enter `1` and then `26`, the variable `choose` will contain `"1\n26\n"`. Using `.trim()` will not remove the newline character in the middle so `.parse()` will encounter an invalid digit.

You should call `choose.clear()` before writing into it again or else use a different variable.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I didn't know that, I did what you told me and It worked! Again Thank you so much for you help, I really appreciate it. Hope you have a wonderful day! ;)